# Images cropped on Blogger

Tags: html, css, image

Why are the pictures on the right side( popular tab) cropped? How can I fix it? They are also cropped here: https://howtoplaystation.blogspot.com/2019/07/blog-post.html at the bottom( in the “YOU MIGHT ALSO LIKE” tab)
Thank you very much in advance!

I have heard that I have to use overflow: visible and position: absolute. But they don't work.

```
#item-thumbnail {
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
}

div.item-thumbnail{
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
}



div.ty-img{
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Using a browser element inspector helps here, you can dig deeper into exactly what attributes are being applied to an element. Have you noticed the `.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail` entry in your CSS? It's applying a specific width/height to those images.

Comment: @JLewkovich Thank you very much! Unfortunately I cannot access these CSSs in Blogger, but I can only add codes. I added .PopularPosts .item-thumbnail {
   width: initial;
   height: initial;
 } and they now look better. Is there any better fix you think?

Comment: @ JLewkovich Can you also help me fix the images here? : https://howtoplaystation.blogspot.com/2019/07/blog-post.html at the bottom( in the “YOU MIGHT ALSO LIKE” tab)?

Comment: I would recommend doing some reading on how to use browser console to inspect CSS on webpage elements, here is a sample tutorial for Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/

Comment: @JLewkovich Thank you! I read it and it is very helpful! But I still didn't manage to fix the blurred images. Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Write the following into css b:skin... with css codes

```
.PopularPosts ul li img{
object-fit: fill!important;
}
```

As about relative posts, you have wright the following:

```
.related-posts .related-thumb {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 100%!important;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks now perfect( a little bit blurred but that's no problem). Can you also help me fix the images here? : http://www.howtoplaystation.com/2019/07/blog-post.html at the bottom( in the “YOU MIGHT ALSO LIKE” tab)? They are all blurred and resized. I can only add CSS, not change them. Thank you

Comment: .related-posts .related-thumb {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 100%!important;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

Comment: @KDVM942 Thank you very much. I’m now not at home and I tried on my phone and it looks like it is still blurred. Am I right?

Comment: With above code , only width and height of related posts image are corrected. As I've checked, maybe is a JavaScript that loads this type of image with this resolution, after page loading there is no CSS to correct this...you have to find the JavaScript in your blogger platform that crops image on this way....

Comment: If you want check my answer as corrected, as is the answer of your first question....Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I can not edit the javascript in Blogger. Can't I just edit my own pictures in Photoshop? What should be then the height and weight?